# How to make my import react Calendar project english only?

Tags: reactjs

Im currently working on a project with React.

When i import a calendar on it, it automaticly change the text in French.

My question : How can i make my project only english? I have the same issue with my contact form with the value of the input directly in french if i dont change by myself.

Hope to be clear.

Cheers.

Comment: What calendar are you importing?

Comment: Im importing react-calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-calendar](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) allows you to define a `locale` prop as an [IETF Language Tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag). If you don't define the `locale`, it defaults to the user's browser language.

```
<Calendar
  onChange={onChange}
  value={value}
  locale="en-GB"
/>
```